# Namespace definition with command=list and multiple instances

Tags: context

I've just begun working on creating a module for ConTeXt (version 2017.05.09), and am running into a rather weird issue where the `command=list` parameter doesn't seem to be respected. To give some context to the issues, it's probably a better idea to put my code first:

```
\startmodule[era]
\definenamespace[era][
    type=module,
    name=era,
    command=list,
    setup=list,
]

\setupera[
    start=,
]

\define[2]\namedordefaulteraparameter{%
    \doifsomethingelse
        {\namederaparameter{#1}{#2}}
        {\namederaparameter{#1}{#2}}
        {\eraparameter{#2}}%
}


\define[1]\doplaceera{%
    #1: \namedordefaulteraparameter{#1}{start}\par
}
\def\placeera[#1]{%
    \processcommalist[#1]\doplaceera%
}


\stopmodule
\endinput
```

And in another file referencing that:

```
\usemodule[era]

\defineera[be,ah,rc,rs][start=0]
\setupera[be][start=1]


\starttext

\placeera[be,rs]

\stoptext
```

From that, I expect to generate a file with the text:

> be: 1
>
> rs: 0

That's not what I'm getting. The "be: 1" works just fine, and if I change the default value of `start` in my module file or include a `\setupera[start=0]` (without a reference to any particular instances) everything shows up like I'd expect, so I know most of the code works. For some reason, though, unless I include one of those manners of compensation, the second line is simply "rs: " as if the `start=0` had never been set.

I looked through the mailing list, and as far as I can tell from [this message](http://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg50984.html) (which seems to be one of the few ones discussing this), everything should be correct. What's particularly strange, though, is that my `\defineera` line works if I *only* try to define `rs` -- as if `\definenamespace` had just been passed `command=yes` -- but `\setupera` is perfectly happy to accept a list (`\setupera[be,rs][start=1]` sets both to 1). Is this an issue in my own code, or is it a bug in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather an interface bug.  The option `command=list` should not be a valid choice.  There are no instances in ConTeXt core where

```
\define<NAME>[...,...][...=...,...=...]
```

would be valid.  I have post this issue on the [mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/088727.html).

However, since you want to use that you can monkey-patch it in.

```
\definenamespace
  [era]
  [
    type=module,
    name=era,
    command=list,
    setup=list,
    set=list,
  ]

\setupera[
    start=,
]

\define[2]\namedordefaulteraparameter{%
    \doifsomethingelse
        {\namederaparameter{#1}{#2}}
        {\namederaparameter{#1}{#2}}
        {\eraparameter{#2}}%
}


\define[1]\doplaceera{%
    #1: \namedordefaulteraparameter{#1}{start}\par
}
\def\placeera[#1]{%
    \processcommalist[#1]\doplaceera
}

\unprotect
\unexpanded\def\defineera{\dotripleempty\patch_define_era}
\def\patch_define_era[#1][#2][#3]{\processcommalist[#1]{\patch_define_era_nested{#2}{#3}}}
\def\patch_define_era_nested#1#2#3{\define_era[#3][#1][#2]}
\protect

\defineera[be,ah,rc,rs][start=0]
\setupera[be][start=1]

\starttext

\placeera[be,rs]

\stoptext
```

Comment: Didn't remember seeing it used before, but I haven't done a lot with external modules before and thought it was just something that didn't see a lot of use. Thanks for the clarification! And I'll definitely be keeping an eye on that thread. For reference, [the wiki page](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Module_Namespaces#Namespace_Configuration) lists it as a valid option as well.